# how to create testing that will check my checksum ( how to make my code corrupted memory )

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I wrote some class that on update of some value - i check the preview checksum and in case checksum is ok i give the option to update the value.

I want to write some test that check the case of the checksum not ok - but i want to do it by doing corrupted memory.

i need to set pointer to the val1 of element 1 in the array and set him to some value - then the checksum will fail .. but i can't find a way to set pointer to this place.

any help please ..

```
// example of corrupted all the array 
CurTesting()
{
     SafeElementManager* ptr = new SafeElementManager();
     void* ptrTmp = &ptr;

     memset(ptrTmp, 0, 4000);
}

class SafeElementManager
{
std::array<Element, 100> _elements;

void setUpdate(std::string key, int val1, int val2, int val3) {...}
}


class Element
{
std::string _key;
int _val1;
int _val2;
int _val3;
int _checkSumVal;

int calcCheckSum(int val1, int val2, int val3) 
{
    return val1 + val2 + val3
}

bool update(int val1, int val2, int val3)
{
    bool retVal = false; 
    int tmp = calcCheckSum(_val1, _val2, _val3);
    if(tmp == _checkSumVal)
    {
        _checkSumVal = tmp;
        _val1 = val1;
        _val2 = val2;
        _val3 = val3;
        retVal = true;
    }

    return retVal;
}
}
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? I mean given the code above it's not going to work because `_val1` is private. But maybe that's not your real problem. You make your question so much clearer if you show us what you tried, and what the problem with it was.

Comment: i dont want to give _val1 to be public and change it in regular way. i want to currant memory on specific val1

Comment: I can corrupt all the array memory with no problem but i don't want .. i need only val1

Comment: Not possible to do in any portable way. But again, it will help if you show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is confused about pointers. This code

```
 SafeElementManager* ptr = new SafeElementManager();
 void* ptrTmp = &ptr;

 memset(ptrTmp, 0, 4000);
```

does not corrupt `SafeElementManager` because you have an extra level of pointers (`ptr` is pointing at the element manager, but `ptrTmp` is pointing at `ptr`, in other words `&ptr` is wrong). The correct code is

```
 SafeElementManager* ptr = new SafeElementManager();
 memset(ptr, 0, 4000);
```

Now we can modify that code to attempt to corrupt only the first `_val1` (in a completely non-portable way of course).

```
 SafeElementManager* ptr = new SafeElementManager();
 char* ptr2 = (char*)ptr;      // char pointer to the beginning of the element manager
 ptr2 += sizeof(std::string);  // skip past the first string
 int* ptr3 = (int*)ptr2;       // now we should be pointing at the first _val1
 memset(ptr3, 0, sizeof(int)); // corrupt it
```

This code assumes that `ptr` equals `&ptr->_elements` equals `&ptr->_elements[0]`, which is probably true, but there are no guarantees.